# Collection groupBy Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

everyone,

I think by now I have searched all over stackoverflow but the solutions I have tried do not work.
With the query I can retrieve data with a one-to-many relationship between DWH.bi_Articles.No and DWH.bi_MagentoPictureBase64.No_Father.
I wanted to try to group the results for DWH.bi_Articles.No so that I could have the fields based on table DWH.bi_MagentoPictureBase64 in a subarray but I keep getting the same error.

"Exception: Property [Item] does not exist on this collection instance. in file /var/www/html/RestApi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php on line 950"

```
public function item_magento_mod($date_mod)
{
    
    $items = DB::table('DWH.bi_Articoli')
                ->join('DWH.bi_MagentoPicture', 'DWH.bi_Articoli.No', '=', 'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.No')
                ->join('DWH.bi_MagentoPictureBase64', 'DWH.bi_Articoli.No', '=', 'DWH.bi_MagentoPictureBase64.No_Father')
                ->where([
                        ['DWH.bi_Articoli.AltJuiMagentoActive', '=', '1'],
                        ['DWH.bi_Articoli.AltJuiAttributeSetId', '>', '0'],
                        ['DWH.bi_Articoli.AltJuiAttributeSetId', '<', '99'],
                        ['DWH.bi_Articoli.SystemModifiedAt', '>=', $date_mod],])
                ->orderBy('DWH.bi_Articoli.No', 'asc')
                ->orderBy('DWH.bi_MagentoPictureBase64.Entry_No', 'asc')
                ->select('DWH.bi_Articoli.No as Item',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.Name',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.Description',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.AttributeSetId',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.InArrivo',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.Visibility',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.Status',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.VatIncluding',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.Price',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.EOL',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.VatProdPostingGroup',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.SecondaryVat',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.MagikExtraFee',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.Ordinabile',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.Prenotabile',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.Npi',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.Ean',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.JuiProductType',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.JuiBaseProductNo',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPicture.JuiConfigurableProductNo',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPictureBase64.Entry_No',
                        'DWH.bi_MagentoPictureBase64.Base64Format'
                    )
                ->get();

    
    $collection = $items->groupBy('Item')
                    ->all();

    //var_dump($collection);


    return $this->handleResponse(ItemMagentoResource::collection($collection), 'All data');
}
```

Does anyone have any advice, I have also deactivated strict from the db configs but nothing changes.

The result without subarray is:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "Item": "ML343ZM/A",
        "Name": "Cinturino Nike Sport Loop Nero 45mm 09/21",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 25,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "49.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252636480",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "CINTURINO_NIKELOOP",
        "Entry_No": 1,
        "Base64": "imagebase64...."
    },
    {
        "Item": "ML343ZM/A",
        "Name": "Cinturino Nike Sport Loop Nero 45mm 09/21",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 25,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "49.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252636480",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "CINTURINO_NIKELOOP",
        "Entry_No": 2,
        "Base64": "imagebase64...."
    },
    {
        "Item": "ML843ZM/A",
        "Name": "Cinturino Nike Sport Platino/Nero 41mm 09/21",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 25,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "49.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252652060",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "CINTURINO_NIKE",
        "Entry_No": 1,
        "Base64": "imagebase64...."
    },
    {
        "Item": "ML843ZM/A",
        "Name": "Cinturino Nike Sport Platino/Nero 41mm 09/21",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 25,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "49.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252652060",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "CINTURINO_NIKE",
        "Entry_No": 2,
        "Base64": "imagebase64...."
    },
    {
        "Item": "ML893ZM/A",
        "Name": "Cinturino Nike Sport Platino/Nero 45mm 09/21  ",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 25,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "49.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252652268",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "CINTURINO_NIKE",
        "Entry_No": 1,
        "Base64": "imagebase64...."
    },
    {
        "Item": "ML893ZM/A",
        "Name": "Cinturino Nike Sport Platino/Nero 45mm 09/21  ",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 25,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "49.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252652268",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "CINTURINO_NIKE",
        "Entry_No": 2,
        "Base64": "imagebase64...."
    },
    {
        "Item": "MM0X3ZM/A",
        "Name": "Portafoglio MagSafe pelle per iPhone - Verde sequoia",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 22,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "65.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252779620",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "WALLET2021",
        "Entry_No": 1,
        "Base64": "imagebase64...."
    },
    {
        "Item": "MM0X3ZM/A",
        "Name": "Portafoglio MagSafe pelle per iPhone - Verde sequoia",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 22,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "65.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252779620",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "WALLET2021",
        "Entry_No": 2,
        "Base64": "imagebase64...."
    },
    {
        "Item": "MM0X3ZM/A",
        "Name": "Portafoglio MagSafe pelle per iPhone - Verde sequoia",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 22,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "65.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252779620",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "WALLET2021",
        "Entry_No": 3,
        "Base64": "imagebase64...."
    }
]
```

}

I would like to get to this instead:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "Item": "ML343ZM/A",
        "Name": "Cinturino Nike Sport Loop Nero 45mm 09/21",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 25,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "49.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252636480",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "CINTURINO_NIKELOOP",
        "Image":[
                {
                    "Entry_No": 1,
                    "Base64": "imagebase64...."
                },
                {
                    "Entry_No": 2,
                    "Base64": "imagebase64...."
                }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Item": "ML843ZM/A",
        "Name": "Cinturino Nike Sport Platino/Nero 41mm 09/21",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 25,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "49.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252652060",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "CINTURINO_NIKE",
        "Image":[
                {
                    "Entry_No": 1,
                    "Base64": "imagebase64...."
                },
                {
                    "Entry_No": 2,
                    "Base64": "imagebase64...."
                }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Item": "ML893ZM/A",
        "Name": "Cinturino Nike Sport Platino/Nero 45mm 09/21  ",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 25,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "49.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252652268",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "CINTURINO_NIKE",
        "Image":[
                {
                    "Entry_No": 1,
                    "Base64": "imagebase64...."
                },
                {
                    "Entry_No": 2,
                    "Base64": "imagebase64...."
                }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Item": "MM0X3ZM/A",
        "Name": "Portafoglio MagSafe pelle per iPhone - Verde sequoia",
        "Description": "",
        "AttributeSetID": 22,
        "InArrive": 0,
        "Visibility": 4,
        "Status": 1,
        "VATIncluding": 1,
        "Price": "65.000000",
        "EOL": 1,
        "VATProdPostingGroup": "SOGG.22%",
        "SecondaryVAT": "SOGG.22%",
        "MagikExtraFee": "",
        "Ordinable": 1,
        "Prenotable": 0,
        "NPI": 0,
        "EAN": "194252779620",
        "JuiProductType": "Standard Product",
        "JuiBaseProductNo": "",
        "JuiConfigurableProductNo": "WALLET2021",
        "Image":[
                {
                    "Entry_No": 1,
                    "Base64": "imagebase64...."
                },
                {
                    "Entry_No": 2,
                    "Base64": "imagebase64...."
                },
                {
                    "Entry_No": 3,
                    "Base64": "imagebase64...."
                }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

ItemMagentoResource:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class ItemMagentoResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {


        return [
            'Item'  => $this->Item,
            'Name'  => $this->Name,
            'Description'  => $this->Description,
            'AttributeSetID'  => $this->AttributeSetId,
            'InArrive'  => $this->InArrivo,
            'Visibility'  => $this->Visibility,
            'Status'  => $this->Status,
            'VATIncluding'  => $this->VatIncluding,
            'Price'  => $this->Price,
            'EOL'  => $this->EOL,
            'VATProdPostingGroup'  => $this->VatProdPostingGroup,
            'SecondaryVAT'  => $this->SecondaryVat,
            'MagikExtraFee'  => $this->MagikExtraFee,
            'Ordinable'  => $this->Ordinabile,
            'Prenotable'  => $this->Prenotabile,
            'NPI'  => $this->Npi,
            'EAN'  => $this->Ean,
            'JuiProductType'  => $this->JuiProductType,
            'JuiBaseProductNo'  => $this->JuiBaseProductNo,
            'JuiConfigurableProductNo'  => $this->JuiConfigurableProductNo,
            'Entry_No'  => $this->Entry_No,
            'Base64'  => $this->Base64Format,
        ];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: which version of laravel are you using ?

Comment: Laravel v8.75.0

Comment: Maybe add the full backtrace of your error message and code of the `ItemMagentoResource:class`

Comment: Edit the post with Resource, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your error is from inside `ItemMagentoResource` class and not from the controller `groupBy('Item')`.

One simple cause would be that you are supposed to send a collection to the resource with `ItemMagentoResource::collection($collection)` but instead you are sending an array since you `$collection` contain the results of `->all()`

A simple solution would be to remove the `->all()`

```
    $collection = $items->groupBy('Item');

    return $this->handleResponse(ItemMagentoResource::collection($collection), 'All data');
```

But also, is your resource class able to handle a collection with grouped results ?
To brutally do that you can use something like `GroupedItemMagentoResource`

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class GroupedItemMagentoResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($collection)
    {
        return ItemMagentoResource::collection($collection);
    }
}
```

And use that in your return

```
$collection = $items->groupBy('Item');

    return $this->handleResponse(GroupedItemMagentoResource::collection($collection), 'All data');
```

Comment: I have the same error without ->all(). I think the problem lies in the resource at this point, but I don't quite understand where.
I have also tried doing a var_dump of the collection directly, but I see all the rows, not a grouping.

Comment: @alby696 edited the answer, give it a try